# nftables drops related traffic

Tags: networking, firewall

When using, for example, an [archwiki example nftables ruleset](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Nftables#Workstation) it contains the line `ct state established,related accept`. This is supposed to accept related and established traffic.

Established works: otherwise, I wouldn't be able to browse the web! Related however, doesn't appear to work.

My proof is my TFTP server: if you [look at the protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_File_Transfer_Protocol#Details), its a simple example of related traffic. However, it only works when my firewall is disabled. TCPdumping the server shows that my server sends the data packet, but never receives an ACK. ([wiki example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_File_Transfer_Protocol#Details) image R2/R3)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conntrack helpers [need to be assigned manually](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Setting_packet_connection_tracking_metainformation) in recent Linux releases.

In nftables it probably looks like this:

```
ct helper tftp {
    type "tftp" protocol udp;
}
chain input {
    udp dport 69 ct helper set tftp
}
```

Comment: Adding this solved it, if you include the step of enabling helpers: `sysctl net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_helper=1`. Alternatively, load the nf_conntrack_tftp module `modprobe nf_conntrack_tftp`, enable helpers and that should solve it too!